# How to move along sinus function at constant speed

Tags: java, function, math

I have a Java program that moves an object according to a sinus function `asin(bx)`.

The object moves at a certain speed by changing the x parameter by the time interval x the speed. However, this only moves the object at a constant speed along the x axis.

What I want to do is move the object at a constant tangential speed along the curve of the function. Could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.   Is the coordinate of your item x=time, y = asin(time)?  Perhaps posting a small snippet of what you've got that isn't doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: What you want to do is to parametrize the sine curve by arc length, and then let your current point = (x(t), y(t)). A web search for "parametrize by arc length" should turn up some formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a function `f(x)` that describes a curve in the `xy` plane. The problem consists in moving a point along this curve at a constant speed `S` (i.e., at a constant tangential speed, as you put it.)

So, let's start at an instant `t` and a position `x`. The point has coordinates `(x, f(x))`. An instant later, say, at `t + dt` the point has moved to `(x + dx, f(x + dx))`.

[image]

The distance between these two locations is:

dist = sqrt((x + dx - dx)<sup>2</sup> + (f(x+dx) - f(x))<sup>2</sup>) = sqrt(dx<sup>2</sup> + (f(x+dx) - f(x))<sup>2</sup>)

Now, let's factor out dx to the right. We get:

dist = sqrt(1 + f'(x)<sup>2</sup>) dx

where f'(x) is the derivative (f(x+dx) - f(x)) /dx.

If we now divide by the time elapsed dt we get

dist/dt = sqrt(1 + f'(x)<sup>2</sup>) dx/dt.

But dist/dt is the speed at which the point moves along the curve, so it is the constant S. Then

S = sqrt(1 + f'(x)<sup>2</sup>) dx/dt

Solving for dx

dx = S / sqrt(1 + f'(x)<sup>2</sup>) dt

which gives you how much you have to move the x-coordinate of the point after dt units of time.

Answer (score 4):

The [arc length on a sine curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Arc_length) as a function of x is an elliptic integral of the second kind. To determine the x coordinate after you move a particular distance (or a particular time with a given speed) you would need to invert this elliptic integral. This is not an elementary function.

There are ways to approximate the inverse of the elliptic integral that are much simpler than you might expect. You could combine a good numerical integration algorithm such as [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) with either Newton's method or binary search to find a numerical root of arc length(x) = kt. Whether this is too computationally expensive depends on how accurate you need it to be and how often you need to update it. The error will decrease dramatically if you estimate the length of one period once, and then reduce t mod the arc length on one period.

Another approach you might try is to use a different curve than a sine curve with a more tractable arc length parametrization. Unfortunately, there are few of those, which is why the arc length exercises in calculus books repeat the same types of curves over and over. Another possibility is to accept a speed that isn't constant but doesn't go too far above or below a specified constant, which you can get with some Fourier analysis.

Another approach is to recognize the arc length parametrization as a solution to a 2-dimensional ordinary differential equation. A first order numerical approximation (Euler's method) might suffice, and I think that's what Leandro Caniglia's answer suggests. If you find that the round off errors are too large, you can use a higher order method such as [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).